# How to Append(store) data from input field Html to a Json File

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to save ( store ) some data from HTML input forms to DB.Json file when i click Insert button from html input form !

This is what i have HTML :

```
<table id="datatable" class="display" style="width:100%">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Surname</th>
<th>Age</th>  
<th>Birthday</th>
<th>Action</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="age" id="age"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="birthday" id="birthday"></td>
<td><button type="button" onclick="insert1()">Insert</button></td>
</tr>
```

now when i fill all fields on html index and click the insert button need to save these data's on json file

Comment: Missing info here. Do you want to submit to a backend and save it there to file or to a DB or do you simply want to collect the info on the client as JSON? If you are looking at sending it to a backend, what backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, place your `<tr>` inside `<tbody>` (it's always a good practice).

Now about your issue. You can't create a separate `DB.json` file with javascript, but you can create a `JSON` object and store values in that.

Then just build your `Json Object`by getting balues by every input `id`

```js
function insert1() {
  myJson = {
    first_name: $("#datatable").find("#first_name").val(),
    last_name: $("#datatable").find("#last_name").val(),
    age: $("#datatable").find("#age").val(),
    birthday: $("#datatable").find("#birthday").val(),
  };
  
  console.log("myJson", myJson);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="datatable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Surname</th>
      <th>Age</th>  
      <th>Birthday</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="age" id="age"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="birthday" id="birthday"></td>
      <td><button type="button" onclick="insert1()">Insert</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time to help me, but i want the input array to save on the DB.json File, i fill all the input forms and click the insert when i check the DB.json file the inputs didnt save ! can you help me on this

Answer (score 0):

you can use `axios` to write in json file

simply it's an `ajax` wrapper

```
axios.post("json file path", jsonObject).then(
  res => console.log(res); /// successfully writing in file
);
```